# HTML Javascript inline popup that is draggable

Tags: javascript, html

Any good code to make inline popups that can be dragged?

In other words a user would click on a link, and it would create this inline popup within the page (so user would interact with both the inline popup of the original page). The user could then drag that popup anywhere they wanted. And they could click on more links to open up more popups....

And a nice bonus feature would be that if a user clicks on a popup, it would be over the other popups (z-index).

Anything come to mind or is this something id mostly need to code myself?

Note: This could be html5 code that won't work in older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/. You can probably customize the JQuery Dialog to do exactly what you want. Draggable is an option and the z-index can be managed through css or directly in the javascript.